Crime drama with supernatural element
I saw this show in probably 2007. My dad rented it from Redbox and we only got one disc from the season I think. The show was like a crime drama and it had supernatural aspects. The only thing I remember clearly is one episode. 
This woman was sitting in her kitchen or dining room and her ceiling fan came loose and dropped down and decapitated her and it turned out that this kid had like telepathy and loosened it. 
And the "cop" or whatever thought that his dad was doing it so he and his partner went to their house when they weren't there and saw that the house was messy and looked like just a kid lived there and they realized the kid had the powers and the dad was scared. 
I've been trying to remember this show for years and I can't remember or find it anywhere.

Welcome to Movies.SE! This seems like a pretty good first question, some good detail, I think I can have a go at tracking this down when I get home.

Could use a better question title, language detail, country info US/UK for instance. Likely release date (not viewing dates unless the same) etc. Not bad for a first attempt.

Yeah I'm sorry about that. I was just trying to remember all the detail I could to get the best answer. I believe it was a US show, it was in English, I assume that it was released around that same time (between 2004 and 2007) and I can't really remember anything else. I would appreciate anything though. Any leads or whatever anyone can dig up. Much appreciated!

Possibly an episode of The Dresden Files (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486657/)?

There's quite a bit of detail that doesn't line up, but the timing works really well that it may have been an episode of Supernatural.  Season 2 aired from September 28, 2006 to May 17, 2007, so it would have made sense for the dvd of the new season to appear at RedBox later that year.
Season 2, episode 5 plot summary:

When Sam has a vision of a man committing a murder-suicide, Ash helps
  the brothers track down Andy Gallagher (Gabriel Tigerman), whose
  mother was killed in the same manner as their own mother—dying in a
  nursery fire. They head to Guthrie, Oklahoma, and Sam is able to stop
  the murder, although the man still ends up killing himself. The
  brothers later locate Andy, and learn that he has mind-control
  abilities. They believe that Andy forced the man to commit suicide.
  However, Sam has another vision of a woman's suicide, and it comes to
  pass while they are talking to Andy, exonerating him. After learning
  that Andy was adopted and that the woman who killed herself is his
  biological mother, they conduct research and discover that he has a
  twin brother named Ansen (Elias Toufexis) that he never knew about.
  Ansen has been using the same ability out of anger to kill those
  connected to the adoption that separated them. He targets Andy's
  ex-girlfriend, and the Winchesters rush to save her. However, Andy
  ends up killing his twin to save Dean, making Sam realize that every
  child connected to Azazel seems to end up becoming a killer. After
  they return to the Roadhouse, Ash reveals that Ansen's adoptive mother
  did not die when he was an infant, meaning not every psychic child
  follows a traceable pattern.


No. Thank you for the attempt but that's not it. I adore Supernatural though :D

My first instinct was to check the Deadly Rotary Fan page on TV Tropes - people getting decapitated by ceiling fans is apparently a trope (also, obligatory warning: TV Tropes Will Ruin Your Life). Anyway, the only matching TV entry was this:

Twiggy's character bites it this way in the Tales from the Crypt episode "The New Arrival." The ceiling fan has some sort of jagged blades affixed to it and lowers itself down to take off her noggin.

I looked up the synopsis for "The New Arrival" and other than that, it doesn't quite match your description: 

The episode aired in 1992.
The man investigating is a child psychiatrist and talk show host who's there to deal with the kid's bad behaviour, rather than a cop. He's also at the house when the decapitation takes place, rather than going there afterwards to investigate.
The dad isn't even present. The child's mother deludedly believes that he's still off fighting World War II.
However, the house is a mess, with the walls covered in chewed bubblegum. It's also revealed at the end that


 The girl is actually a zombie and has been dead for 40 years.

So there's still a chance that this is what you're looking for. Just in case, here's the full episode:




No I had seen that when I was searching. That's a good guess but that wasn't it. The "cop" from the show I'm looking for was younger and the show was newer than that. I appreciate your help though! I just have to keep looking
